# Creating a Registry text file with vbs

Tags: vbscript, registry

I am trying to create a registry backup that I can read using VBS.  I found a script online that seems to do the trick however, it only goes one file of the Hive deep.

This code:

```
Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT   = &H80000000
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER   = &H80000001
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE  = &H80000002
Const HKEY_USERS          = &H80000003
Const HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG = &H80000004
strKeyPath = ""

Sub EnumerateKeys(hive, key, f)
  f.WriteLine( key)
  reg.EnumKey hive, key, arrSubKeys

  If Not IsNull(arrSubKeys) Then
    For Each subkey In arrSubKeys
      EnumerateKeys hive, key & "\" & subkey, f
    Next
  End If
End Sub

Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")



Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
path = <Path to Text file>
If fso.FileExists(path) Then

Else
    Set file = fso.CreateTextFile(path)
End If

EnumerateKeys HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, file
```

executes to

> \BCD00000000 
>   \HARDWARE 
>   \SAM 
>   \SECURITY 
>   \SOFTWARE 
>   \SYSTEM

and only seems to go the first file path deep.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can't back up the registry in code. Some parts of it only System has access. Two of your things are virtual keys (`HKCR` is built from `HKCU\Software\Classes and HKLM\Software\Classes`). `HKCU` is a subkey of `HKUsers`. Use the `REG` command line command (`Reg Save /?` and `Reg Restore /?` - see `Reg /?`.

Comment: I don't know if this [script](https://superuser.com/questions/1484476/how-i-can-delete-all-keys-that-cointain-programname?answertab=active#tab-top) can help you or not ?
This script will search your Registry and find all instances of the search string you input and create a temporary file that can be opened by WordPad.

***NOTE:*** This file will be deleted when you close WordPad. You must manually save this file to a new location if you want to refer to it again later.
If you save the file with a `.reg` extension, you can use it to `restore` any Registry changes you make to these values.

Comment: By default `.reg` files are encoded as UTF-16. I don't know how to create UTF-16 files in VBScript. Better use the `reg.exe` program to backup your registry (you may call `reg.exe` from vbscript if you prefer).